# Import Sass variables into angular 5 component's typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-cli

I want to share some scss variables with my javascript.

So far I have done the following but it isn't working.

**Component**

```
import * as variables from 'sass-variable-loader!../styles/_variables.scss';
```

**.angular.cli.json**

```
...
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/sass-variable-loader/dist/index.js"
],
...
```

I also change the `typings.d.ts` file to accept files ending in `.scss`.

I realize I'm not adding the `sass-variable-loader` to a webpack configuration but doesn't angular use that under the hood anyways? Is there a way for me to add the sass-variable-loader without out explicitly specifying it in a webpack configuration?

OR

Is there another way to load this file and share the variables with my typescript files?

**EDIT**

If I do `import * as variables from '../styles/_variables.scss'` then I get the error message `Cannot find module` from webpack during compilation.

Comment: can you provide a sample plunk

Comment: where is your variable.scss, it could be a path issue

Comment: What error do you get? try `const styles = require('../styles/_variables.scss); (with correctly path)`

Comment: @David Require doesn't work in the angular app and I would like to do this without using require if it's possible.

Comment: @Akanksha It's definitely not a path issue. I will paste the error message.

Comment: @christo8989 did you figure this out?

Comment: @christo8989, Did you find a solution?

Comment: I changed my solution so I won’t need this but I’ve been meaning to create a stackblitz to address the issue. I just haven’t had time.